# context menu in thunar does not work properly

Tags: xubuntu, menu, thunar

[image]Running Xubuntu Bionic. After an update of the system that did not terminate well I cannot use my personal thunar context menus : 
My context menu for searching a file in a directory does not show the type in window.
whereas the rename context menu works properly.

Complement : the file ~/;config/thunar/uca.xml is correct. The

When I right click on a directory on the context menu search file, a windows should popup in which I can type the name of the file. This window does not pop up.

Comment: Are you referring to your custom actions? `~/.config/Thunar/uca.xml` is the file holding these actions. I don't know what you mean by "My context menu for searching a file in a directory does not show the type in window." Is that related to Catfish? Can you post an image of your context menu? You'll need to use xfce4-screenshooter with a convenient delay.

Answer (score 1):

Shame on me. It is just that catfish disappeared from my configuration.